# Jenkins pipeline fails with No such property error

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I have Jenkins container (version 2.138.1) with a pipeline which uses the plugins:

Job DSL version 1.7.0

Repository Connector version 1.1.3

P4 version 1.8.14

it fails with the below error:

```
11:23:17 ERROR: (int_dbp_ci.groovy, line 7) No such property: IntDBCIProperties for class: int_dbp_ci
```

what's strange, in the same machine, in other Jenkins container, for the same job with the same exact syntax and plugins version, it works. any idea what might cause the issue?

Comment: It's hard to guess what might be wrong without a reproducible example of the pipeline. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with one of the options present in global security configuration “ Enable script security for job DSL scripts”, which needs to be unchecked.